# Show escaped string as Unicode in Python

Tags: python, unicode, escaping

i have just known Python for few days. Unicode seems to be a problem with Python.

i have a text file stores a text string like this

```
'\u0110\xe8n \u0111\u1ecf n\xfat giao th\xf4ng Ng\xe3 t\u01b0 L\xe1ng H\u1ea1'
```

i can read the file and print the string out but it displays incorrectly.
How can i print it out to screen correctly as follow:

```
"Đèn đỏ nút giao thông Ngã tư Láng Hạ"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: By "print the string", do you mean to a console? If so, it's probably your console that's the problem - are you sure it supports Unicode characters?

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> x=r'\u0110\xe8n \u0111\u1ecf n\xfat giao th\xf4ng Ng\xe3 t\u01b0 L\xe1ng H\u1ea1'
>>> u=unicode(x, 'unicode-escape')
>>> print u
Đèn đỏ nút giao thông Ngã tư Láng Hạ
```

This works in a Mac, where Terminal.App correctly makes `sys.stdout.encoding` be set to `utf-8`.  If your platform doesn't set that attribute correctly (or at all), you'll need to replace the last line with

```
print u.decode('utf8')
```

or whatever other encoding your terminal/console is using.

Note that in the first line I assign a raw string literal so that the "escape sequences" would not be expanded -- that just mimics what would happen if bytestring `x` was being read from a (text or binary) file with that literal content.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to show a simple example with code and output what you have explicitly tried.  At a guess your console doesn't support Vietnamese.  Here are some options:

```
# A byte string with Unicode escapes as text.
>>> x='\u0110\xe8n \u0111\u1ecf n\xfat giao th\xf4ng Ng\xe3 t\u01b0 L\xe1ng H\u1ea1'

# Convert to Unicode string.
>>> x=x.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> x
u'\u0110\xe8n \u0111\u1ecf n\xfat giao th\xf4ng Ng\xe3 t\u01b0 L\xe1ng H\u1ea1'

# Try to print to my console:
>>> print x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\dev\python\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u0110' in position 0:
  character maps to <undefined>

# My console's encoding is cp437.
# Instead of the default strict error handling that throws exceptions, try:
>>> print x.encode('cp437','replace')
?èn ?? nút giao thông Ng? t? Láng H?    

# Six characters weren't supported.
# Here's a way to write the text to a temp file and display it with another
# program that supports the UTF-8 encoding:
>>> import tempfile
>>> f,name=tempfile.mkstemp()
>>> import os
>>> os.write(f,x.encode('utf8'))
48
>>> os.close(f)
>>> os.system('notepad.exe '+name)
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
>>> s=u"\u0110\xe8n \u0111\u1ecf n\xfat giao th\xf4ng Ng\xe3 t\u01b0 L\xe1ng H\u1ea1"
>>> print s
=> Đèn đỏ nút giao thông Ngã tư Láng Hạ
```